# Pulling proxyAddresses from a single sign on login

Tags: graph, oauth, azure-active-directory, office365

We have a web page using microsoft single sign on. When we redirect the user to login to our application, we send them to :
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?scope=user.read&response_type=code&client_id=a5342222-a222-222d-87c3-222222222222&redirect_uri=${ourappurl}/office365handler](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?scope=user.read&response_type=code&client_id=a5342222-a222-222d-87c3-222222222222&redirect_uri=$%7Bourappurl%7D/office365handler)

We want to be able to access the user's proxyAddresses (their alias emails) as often users are not using their upn to receive emails. When the user logs in, we are unable to call

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=proxyAddresses

as we get Access Denied.

Do we need to redirect the user to login.microsoftonline.com with additional scopes? If so, which scope do we need? We've gone over the docs but can't find anything relevant.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

•   As you are encountering ‘Access denied’ Status code 400 message after running the query in Microsoft Graph Explorer while retrieving the details of proxy addresses of the signed in users, you have not provided appropriate permissions to Microsoft Graph API for accessing and reading the users data in your tenant. To do so, please provide the below permissions to Microsoft Graph API and Explorer application and ensure that Admin consent is allowed for each permission requested below: -

Go to Azure AD in your tenant --> Enterprise Applications --> Graph Explorer --> Permissions --> In that, search for the below permissions and select them, please select these permissions under ‘admin consent’ tab as below: -

‘ Directory.AccessAsUser.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, User.Read, User.ReadBasic.All, User.ReadWrite, User.ReadWrite.All’(These permissions are required at least to read users’ data in Azure AD)

[image: Graph explorer permissions]
[image: Graph explorer permissions-2]
[image: Graph explorer permissions-3]

Once, these permissions are granted, you will be able to run the graph query and gain the output correctly. Also, please find the below graph query to read any users’ proxy addresses through graph explorer.

' https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.com?$select=proxyaddresses '